# Setting input value using document.getElementById not truely setting the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input:

```
<input type="text" class="input" name="email" id="email" value="" disabled>
```

And JavaScript:

```
$email = "stackemail@emails.com";

function setEmail(email) {
        document.getElementById("email").value = email;
    }

    window.onload = setEmail($email);
```

Now, it does show the email in the input field just how i want it to:
[image: it does show stackemail@emails.com]

But it doesn't set the value when i inspect the element:
[image: the value = ""]

Even when i change the value inside the inspect element, it stays "stackemail@emails.com"

Now i need the value to be the same as what it is showing
Why is it not doing so?

Comment: to set the value attribute, use .setAttribute. check this fiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/evhzofz2/1/ (and inspect elements)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are updating it `value` property of the DOM element and not its value attribute. To reflect in the markup use [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) which is using to update an attribute.

```
function setEmail(email) {
   document.getElementById("email").setAttribute('value', email);
}
```

```js
$email = "stackemail@emails.com";

function setEmail(email) {
  document.getElementById("email").setAttribute("value", email);
  document.getElementById("email2").value = email;
}

window.onload = setEmail($email);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input" name="email" id="email" value="" disabled>

<input type="text" class="input" name="email" id="email2" value="" disabled>
```

Comment: fiddle with the two elements printed (if needed): https://jsfiddle.net/evhzofz2/1/ (using both `setAttribute` and `value`)

Answer (score 2):

Works anyway... the inspector not show ur changes, if u want try use setAttribute function but works fine

```js
    $email = "stackemail@emails.com";

    function setEmail(email) {
          document.getElementById("email").value = email;
    //if u want change attr.. try works too
      //document.getElementById("email").setAttribute('value',email);
        }
    function getEmail(){
      return document.getElementById("email").value;
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
      setEmail($email);
      console.log('value: ' + getEmail());
    });
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input" name="email" id="email" value="" disabled />
```